# Python 2 and Python 3 mixing error with virtual environments?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, virtualenv

1) I installed python3.5 on windows with the installer. I checked set to path.

2) I installed python2.7 on windows with the installer. I checked set to path.

- python 3 is found in C:\Users\amand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32
- python 2 is found in C:\Python27

3) I open the command prompt

```
>>> python -m venv tutorial-env
C:\Python27\python.exe: No module named venv
```

Okay....so how about...

```
>>>py -3
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit      
(Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>>python -m venv tutorial-env
>File "<stdin>", line 1
python -m venv tutorial-env
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Okay. I closed my command prompt and started a new one. The document said to use this...but...

```
>>>>python3 -m venv tutorial-env
'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Documentation that I am referring to
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to use a specific python you can do:

```
python3 -m venv tutorial-env #for python 3
python2 -m venv tutorial-env #for python 2
#if you have multple versions of 3 or 2
python2.7 -m venv tutorial-env #for python 2.7
python3.5 -m venv tutorial-env #for python 3.5 or something along the lines
```

**EDIT**

If in Windows and the aboves not working:

```
#In command prompt
py -3 #or -2
>>> import venv
>>> venv.main('tutorial-env')
```

or

```
py -3 -m venv tutorial-env
```

Comment: 'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. As well as the other versions of pythons too.

Comment: @BHok could you try: `python-3.5.2.exe -m venv tutorial-env`

Comment: Sorry I wasn't much help I'm using OsX right right so I couldn't test anything. the last thing I can think of is `py -3 -m venv tutorial-env`

Comment: If that doesn't work, see my edit, that works for sure